BehaviourDesigner Runtime Squads for new Formations
I'm struggling to make a new "Squad" at runtime from group selection to move in BehaviourDesigners Formations.
The code for what I've done but this would turn this question into a novel, so..
A Squad is generated at the end of using a selection box to get a group of Units.
In the Squad class it adds/removes members, keeps track of who is in the squad and who the leaderis, and if the leader is removed(killed) a new member is appointed and the members Behaviours local shared variable reference to point to the new leader, while also setting the new leaders reference to null.
It sort of works but I'm sure im missing where each members index should be set or something as I get an out of bounds exception, plus they apear to be out of order with missing spots in the formation (using column for its simplicity).
I can add code if needed
Any help or pointers on how to do this correctly much appreciated.
Edit: Added Code
Squad class to keep track of the groups
public class Squad
{
    public MobileUnit leader;
    public List<MobileUnit> members = new List<MobileUnit>();

    public Squad(MobileUnit squadLeader)
    {
        leader = squadLeader;
        members.Add(leader);
    }

    public void AddUnit(MobileUnit unit)
    {
        if (!members.Contains(unit))
        {
            members.Add(unit);
            unit.AI.SetVariableValue("SquadLeader", leader.gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveUnit(MobileUnit unit)
    {
        if (members.Contains(unit))
        {
            members.Remove(unit);
        }   
        
        if (unit == leader)
        {
            if (members.Count > 0)
            {
                leader = members[0];
                leader.AI.SetVariableValue("SquadLeader", null);
                UpdateMembers();
            }
        }
        
        unit.AI.SetVariableValue("SquadLeader", null);
    }


    public void UpdateMembers()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < members.Count; x++)
        {
            if (members[x] != leader)
            {
                members[x].AI.SetVariableValue("SquadLeader", leader.gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}

Method used to generate the Squad
private Squad GenerateNewSquadFromSelectedUnits(List<MobileUnit> units)
{
    if (units.Count > 0)
    {
        Squad squad = new Squad(units[0]);
        
        for (int x = 1; x < units.Count; x++)
        {
            squad.AddUnit(units[x]);
        }

        return squad;
    }
    
    Debug.LogWarning("Trying to create squad from empty selection");
    return null;
}

Exception
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index must be within the bounds of the List.
Parameter name: index
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].Insert (System.Int32 index, T item) (at <a3b02d6f9b494355b946095ea1f25c54>:0)
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Formations.Tasks.FormationGroup.AddAgentToGroup (BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Behavior agent, System.Int32 index) (at Assets/Behaviour/Behavior Designer Formations/Scripts/Tasks/FormationGroup.cs:231)
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Formations.Tasks.NavMeshFormationGroup.AddAgentToGroup (BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Behavior agent, System.Int32 index) (at Assets/Behaviour/Behavior Designer Formations/Scripts/Tasks/NavMeshFormationGroup.cs:108)
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Behavior.SendEvent[T,U] (System.String name, T arg1, U arg2) (at <90551af678e744f281eb5fcd0aa81afc>:0)
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Formations.Tasks.FormationGroup.AddAgentToGroup (BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Behavior agent, System.Int32 index) (at Assets/Behaviour/Behavior Designer Formations/Scripts/Tasks/FormationGroup.cs:216)
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Formations.Tasks.NavMeshFormationGroup.AddAgentToGroup (BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Behavior agent, System.Int32 index) (at Assets/Behaviour/Behavior Designer Formations/Scripts/Tasks/NavMeshFormationGroup.cs:108)
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Formations.Tasks.FormationGroup.StartListeningForOrders (BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Behavior agent) (at Assets/Behaviour/Behavior Designer Formations/Scripts/Tasks/FormationGroup.cs:168)
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Behavior.SendEvent[T] (System.String name, T arg1) (at <90551af678e744f281eb5fcd0aa81afc>:0)
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Formations.Tasks.FormationGroup.OnUpdate () (at Assets/Behaviour/Behavior Designer Formations/Scripts/Tasks/FormationGroup.cs:375)
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.BehaviorManager.RunTask (BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.BehaviorManager+BehaviorTree behaviorTree, System.Int32 taskIndex, System.Int32 stackIndex, BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.Tasks.TaskStatus previousStatus) (at <90551af678e744f281eb5fcd0aa81afc>:0)
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.BehaviorManager.Tick (BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.BehaviorManager+BehaviorTree behaviorTree) (at <90551af678e744f281eb5fcd0aa81afc>:0)
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.BehaviorManager.Tick () (at <90551af678e744f281eb5fcd0aa81afc>:0)
BehaviorDesigner.Runtime.BehaviorManager.Update () (at <90551af678e744f281eb5fcd0aa81afc>:0)


We'll need to see your code to help you troubleshoot the out of bounds error. Showing examples of the missing spots vs what you expect the formation to look like instead could also help.

@DMGregory I've added my code (minimal) and the Exception :/

But the error message does not appear to match the code you posted. Your error seems to happen in the FormationGroup code, not in Squad

@Zibelas yes its part of the BehaviourDesigner addon which I seem to be trying to implement wrong

Maybe you do but the error and the code do not match. And both your UpdateMember and Remove Unit look weird
